# Is it possible to add dynamic value to @Html.ActionLink param

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a method in my MVC controller, that when invoked downloads a document.

I have a bootstrap Modal, where the href resides which points to this method.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { applicantId = 1, templateId = 1 })
```

The applicantId and templateId for the minute are hardcoded, but these values are passed to the Modal via jquery as  text values.

Is it possible to get a HTML id dynamically and add it to the @Html.ActionLink?

**Modal:**

```
<div id="template1">
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <h3 id="app" style="display:none"></h3>
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Letter Template Logo</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <img style="background-size:cover;" src="~/Content/images/image.png" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                 ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { applicantId = 1, templateId = 1 })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its not really clear what your asking here. `@Html.ActionLink()` is razor code and is parsed on the server before its sent to the view, so if you want to change the generated `href` attribute based on data only available in the client then you need javascript. And you cannot use ajax to download a file. You need to redirect to the method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah after posting, i read on not being able to do this via ajax. I am asking, can I bind the a value passed into the modal to the html.actionlink param?

Comment: You need to use javascript/jquery to change the `href` attribute. Alternatively, cancel the default action and build your own url and use `location.href` to redirect and download the file. (bit hard to give an answer when you have not shown the controller method or indicated where the values of `applicantId` and `templateId` come from)

Comment: The values come from a dropdownlist, so if I can change the attribute with javascript, is it better to use an "a" tag instead of @html.actionlink?

Comment: It makes no difference (`@Html.ActionLink()` just generates a `<a>` tag - and its always better to use `ActionLink()` because it ensure your url will be correct)

Comment: okay cool, finally this attribute change has to happen before the link is clicked correct? I assume, once ActionLink is clicked it will fire over to mvc routing before the attribute will change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147411/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-haris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created .NetFiddle. It works [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fw1eMb)

You can change `Html.ActionLink()` method parameters with `.replace()` method and you can implement like following.

**//html**

```
Parameter 1:<input id="param1" />
Parameter 2:<input id="param2" />

<div class="modal-footer">
    @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Example", new { applicantId = 1, templateId = 1 })
</div>

<button id="yourbutton">Change Action Link</button>
```

**//jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
$("#yourbutton").on("click",function(){

    var param1 = $("#param1").val();
    var param2 = $("#param2").val();
    console.log(param1);
    console.log(param2);

    var link = '@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Example", 
                    new { applicantId  = "_applicantId_",  templateId = "_templateId_"})';
    if(param1 == "" || param2 == "")
    {
        alert("please fill all parameter inputs")
    }
    else
    {
        link = link.replace('_applicantId_', param1);
        link = link.replace('_templateId_', param2);
        $(".modal-footer").html(link)
        alert("I have changed ActionLink. Please click the download link")

    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, I did manage to do this in the end. I do like your solution. so will up vote :)

Comment: your welcome :) if this solution works for your question please consider to accept the answer to help people understand it has been solved :)

Comment: tried this actually and it only appends the link as text in the modal footer

Comment: @Haris there is only action link in Your modal footer right

Comment: yeah it is only one, yeah works in the fiddle must be something i am doing sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Pond", "Pond", "Home", htmlAttributes: new  { 
@class="classNameYouWantToAdd" })
```

or

```
@Html.ActionLink("Pond", "Pond", "Home", new  { 
@class="classNameYouWantToAdd" })
```

if you want to do it from JQuery then you can either target the li tag that contains the link or Add a class name to the your action link like above and then update the class of the object as your normally would.

```
 $('.TargetedClassNameOfActionLink').addClass('addDifferentClass').removeClass('removeSomeOtherClass')





$('#liTagId').find('.ClassNameOfActionLink').addClass('addDifferentClass').removeClass('removeSomeOtherClass')
```

or

```
$('#tabPond').addClass("greenTab");
```